# C++ - Integer Divides by Integer Returns Wrong Answer

Tags: c++

Can anyone enlighten me on the code below? I am totally baffled by the answer, it keeps returning 138934. I am currently using Code::Blocks.

Am i declaring or doing something totally wrong? Pardon the basic question, I have been checking on this and not getting any answer online.

```
int amount, fifties;
fifties= amount/50;

cout<<"Please enter amount: ";
cin>>amount;

cout<<"You have entered: "<<amount<<endl;
cout<<"Answer: "<<fifties<<endl;
```

Comment: `amount` is uninitialised; so it has garbage value.

Comment: Just move the second line to the sixth (cut & paste)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code that you have posted, `amount` is not initialised;

So the line `fifties= amount/50;` results in `fifties` having random garbage value.

To overcome, you must assign some value to `amount` as:

```
int amount=100
```

or ideally, move the line `fifties= amount/50;` below `cin>>amount`.  By writing 
`fifties= amount/50;` below the `cin>>amount` line, you are making sure that `amount` contains the value entered by the user.  So, you perform valid division in the next line, which results in `fifties` containing the expected answer.

Working code [**here**](http://ideone.com/TgfR7P).

Comment: I have moved the line lower. It is working fine now. Was thinking for 30 minutes, sadly. Much thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just move the `fifties = amount / 50;` line *after* the `cin >> amount;` line, so that `amount` has a useful value first.

Comment: Thank you for the enlightenment. This is something new to me, will take note on this. Much thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the value of "amount" and calculate the fifties after receiving the input value from user.

Uninitialized value amount will contain garbage value and you are calculating the fifties even before you receive the input